# How to use Windows authentication and authorization in my asp.net mvc app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.net MVC EF 2.0 application, regular users use Windows authentication through AD. there are also some other sections (components) only allow Admin users to access such as special reports etc, so the site admin creates new Admin user and send an email with the temporary password (the admin user id will still use user's ID from Active directory), when the new Admin user receives the email and change the password, then he/she can log in the site through a login form, and after login, the new admin user can see more functions and reports to access, since the site form shows user id, I can see the admin's active directory id is showing in the sites. This is all how it works in ASP.net MVC EF 2.0.

But after we converted this site to ASP.net MVC EF 4.6, and run it in Integrated mode with Anonymous Authentication disabled, after Admin user login, the functions and reports to be accessed by Admin users are not available anymore (hidden), apparently, the Admin user are not be recognized even the ID field on view (form) is still showing admin user id of Active Directory. 
Can anybody help me resolve this issue? Is this related to the conflicts of Windows Forms and Windows authentication as somebody mentioned in the internet? or it is related Windows authentication only? What is the standard way to build this kind application in MVC 4.6 framework? thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this in fact an IIS application?

Comment: Any asp.net mvc application relies on IIS, I think it is related. ideally, I don't need to change the design source file and only do some configuration from IIS. But for this case, I don't think that is the case. Please let me know if anybody has any ideas and has the similar issue. Thanks

Comment: It is not as simple as configuring IIS. Please [read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx)

Comment: Actually, I read that article, the business scenario is not exactly same. I can not confirm my application is the mixed Forms and Windows authentication. Basically, it is just some potions of sites allow Admin users to see and function after the admin user login in from a login form. The admin user login through the same Active Directory id, the only thing is the password required. It looks like Windows form, but I am not sure. In other words, all users (Normal users and Admin users) are relying on the user name from AD,the only difference is Admin user requires password to see more functions.

Comment: There is no reason this shouldn't work.  Best not to think of this as Forms Authentication.  It's really just Windows Integrated security.  Just have a UI for a user to enter admin credentials and unlock admin functionality.

Comment: So my understanding is that it is still windows auth but different roles. Then it is no longer authentication but authorization. There are plenty of examples online and in the docs on how to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, I just want to make sure I am focusing on the correct direction with investigation. Basically, it is about to make the app to be built into Internet Information Services to password protect the views in the MVC application and allow controller actions to be invoked only by particular Windows users or users who are members of particular Windows groups. so now it is clear that it is not a Form Authentication application. But the fact is that the portions of site should be available for admin user are not showing when run it in EF 4.6 with Integrated mode.

Comment: @CodingYoshi: thank you so much for your clarification... So now, I can further narrow down to focus on the topic of Authorization. Basically, Adding User and Group Access to a Controller of this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(v=vs.98).aspx help me a lot, but I will be looking more site to get help, thanks a lot,

Comment: “Windows Forms” is a reserved term for the desktop framework. If you are using Forms authentication, make sure you modify the question to eliminate the incorrect usage.

Comment: It depends on what "not available anymore (hidden)" means. Hidden from the menu? Then go look at the code that hides stuff on the menu!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, thanks a lot, yes, the hides are in the menu on the left menu which shows more menu options for Admin users (roles), I will check the razor view on Monday to see how they are hidden and why the user.Identity is not returned proper role value, and may need to modify the source code after that,